# Differentiating between Parent Features and Called Features in Karate DSL

Tags: karate

In Karate DSL, we can call another 'reusable' Feature from inside another feature ([see these examples](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-other-feature-files))

On the other hand, Karate also offers custom hooks by implementing `RuntimeHook` and overriding default hooks ([see these examples](https://github.com/kirksl/karate-maven-gradle/blob/master/src/test/java/KarateHook.java) and [these](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/develop/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/RuntimeHook.java))

One problem I'm facing now is how to get my `afterFeature` hooks to NOT execute after a 'Called Feature'/reusable feature is ran.

I tried looking into the code of Karate to see how they're able to distinguish between Parent Feature and Called Feature but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RuntimeHook` gives you the `ScenarioRuntime` on the method signature / callbacks, which has a `caller` public property of type `ScenarioCall`. You can look at the [`depth` or call `isNone()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.4.0/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/core/ScenarioCall.java#L73) on `caller` and I think that should get you going.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I want to confirm that basically we need to check `if ScenarioCall.depth` is NOT 0, then it's a 'called feature', right?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: how to use it? karate.scenarioCall.depth is this the right way